# Angular 7 pattern validation allowing input that shouldn't be allowed

Tags: regex, angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

We have a Java API that validates incoming messages using an XSD. For validating phone numbers it uses the following pattern:

```
((085)[-]?[0-9]{7})|((088)[-]?[0-9]{7})|(((0)[1-9]{2}[0-9][-]?[1-9][0-9]{5})|((\\+31|0|0031)[1-9][0-9][-]?[1-9][0-9]{6}))|((06)[-]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7})|(((\\+31|0|0031)6){1}[-]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7})|\\+(1\d{4,14}|2[078]\\d{3,13}|3[0-469]\\d{3,13}|4[013-9]\\d{3,13}|5[1-8]\\d{3,13}|6[0-6]\\d{3,13}|7\\d{4,14}|8[1-469]\\d{3,13}|9[0-58]\\d{3,13}|[2-9]\\d{4,14})
```

I've created a form using this exact pattern, taking care to use double backslashes:

```
this.inputForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        phonenumber: ['', Validators.pattern('((085)[-]?[0-9]{7})|((088)[-]?[0-9]{7})|(((0)[1-9]{2}[0-9][-]?[1-9][0-9]{5})|((\\+31|0|0031)[1-9][0-9][-]?[1-9][0-9]{6}))|((06)[-]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7})|(((\\+31|0|0031)6){1}[-]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7})|\\+(1\\d{4,14}|2[078]\\d{3,13}|3[0-469]\\d{3,13}|4[013-9]\\d{3,13}|5[1-8]\\d{3,13}|6[0-6]\\d{3,13}|7\\d{4,14}|8[1-469]\\d{3,13}|9[0-58]\\d{3,13}|[2-9]\\d{4,14})')],
    });
```

This works for the most part, but it's still allowing certain numbers that the XSD rejects. For instance, I can put in 061234567912345678 and the validator will allow it, but the XSD will not.  Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe a typo: `1\d{4,14}` instead of `1\\d{4,14}`

Answer (score 0):

`061234567912345678`  matches `(06)[-]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}`, I think you should use `^(((085)[-]?[0-9]{7})|((088)[-]?[0-9]{7})|(((0)[1-9]{2}[0-9][-]?[1-9][0-9]{5})|((\\+31|0|0031)[1-9][0-9][-]?[1-9][0-9]{6}))|((06)[-]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7})|(((\\+31|0|0031)6){1}[-]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7})|\\+(1\d{4,14}|2[078]\\d{3,13}|3[0-469]\\d{3,13}|4[013-9]\\d{3,13}|5[1-8]\\d{3,13}|6[0-6]\\d{3,13}|7\\d{4,14}|8[1-469]\\d{3,13}|9[0-58]\\d{3,13}|[2-9]\\d{4,14}))$` as a regex (added `^(` at the begining and `)$`at the end) it matches the begining and end of the string (in between are your different possible regex)